# Bluetooth communication between Android and Arduino doesn't always work

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

The communication was successful the first or second time, then it fails randomly and confuses me. I am using Bluetooth to control my LED strip's color, brightness and pattern. I have a spinner to control the pattern.

First, when the spinner item was chosen, it sends an 'm' to indicate that the next value is going to assign to a variable that identifies the mode is selected. Then a value follows (eg 1 = mode1, 2= mode2). So I have to send 2 bytes of data at once.

The spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                msg("In ed!");
                break;
            case 1:
                try {
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write('m');
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write(1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    msg("Error1");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                try {
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write('m');
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write(2);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    msg("Error2");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                try {
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write('m');
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write(3);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    msg("Error3");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Bluetooth part of the Arduino code:

```
if(BT.available()>1) {
  COMMAND = (char)BT.read();
  inputVal = (int)BT.read();
  switch(COMMAND) {
    case 'm':
      modeSelected = inputVal;
      break;
    case 'c':
      colorOffset1 = inputVal;
      break;
    case 'b':
      brightness = inputVal;
      break;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a character for end packet. In your code, the packet order my get wrong. Somehow, arduino may get "m1m" message and it will confuse.

lets say your and character is "x", then add your end character into your all android packets:

```
btSocket.getOutputStream().write('m');
btSocket.getOutputStream().write(1);
btSocket.getOutputStream().write('x');
```

change your android code:

```
in global:
char msg[2];
int index = 0;

if(BT.available()>0) {
  char c = (char)BT.read();
  if (c == 'x') {
     COMMAND = msg[0];
     inputVal = (int)msg[1];
     switch(COMMAND) {
       case 'm':
         modeSelected = inputVal;
         break;
       case 'c':
         colorOffset1 = inputVal;
         break;
       case 'b':
         brightness = inputVal;
         break;
     }
  } else {
     msg[index%2] = c;
     index ++;
  }
}
```

I did not test the code, it may fail. But I wrote the code for the idea.

Comment: It does work! Thanks you man!, but i still have a problem here. Its won't always work as well if i don't put a delay on Arduino.The Arduino only receives data if i put delay(10) on it. However, delay is not allowed in my project which is LED strip animation so that lighting processing speed is required. Now i am considering that i buy another Arduino board that only for receiving data from Bluetooth and I2C.

Comment: you dont need to add delay into arduino code. Can you try add some delay between BT send command in Android? it will be like that

btSocket.getOutputStream().write('m');
try {
    Thread.sleep(50);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
btSocket.getOutputStream().write(1);

Comment: It's still doesn't work sometime but that's is acceptable.Thanks for your help bro!